# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

This is a game that asks users to enter a location on a 3 by 3 grid and then another user attempts to guess the location. Having a problem debugging an error.

What is the problem with this line?   `Col=int(guess[1:])-1`

In the following code?

It returns the following error when I try and run it in repl.it.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 84, in
>      File "python", line 71, in *init* ValueError: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
#Creation of the grid and the user interface list
grid = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
turns=0
guess="x"
#Function to clear screen
def cls(): 
  print ("\n" * 100)

#Function to validate coordinate
def validate_entry():
  valid=False
  while valid==False:
    guess=input("Enter a location from A1 to C3: ")
    loc = guess.upper() #Use upper case
    row = guess[0:1]
    col = guess[1:2]
    if(row!="A" and row!="B" and row!="C") or (col!="1" and col!="2" and col!="3"):
      print("Your location is invalid.")
      print("")
      return False #not actually needed, but helps see what is happening
    else:
     valid=True
     return True
#Function to set the location of the treasure
def settingTreasure(grid):

    treasureSet=input("Set location by entering a location from A1 to C3: ")
    #Converting the letter into a coordinate in the list
    treasure_letter=str(treasureSet[:1])
    if treasure_letter in ["a", "A"]:
      locRow=0
    elif treasure_letter in ["b", "B"]:
      locRow=1
    elif treasure_letter in ["c", "C"]:
      locRow=2
    #Converting the number into a list coordinate
    locCol=int(treasureSet[1:])-1
    grid[locRow][locCol]=1

settingTreasure(grid)
cls()
#Displaying the user interface in a clean manner
def gameBoard():
  UI = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  for i in range(0,len(UI)):
    print(UI[i])

gameBoard()

#The main loop that contains the game
def _init_(turns, guess):
  turns=turns+1
 #If the player exceeds three turns they lose
  if turns>3:
    print("Too many turns! You lose!")
    quit()

  #Prints number of turns
  print(" ")
  print("Turn " + str(turns))
  validate_entry()
  #Converting the letter into a coordinate in the list
  guess_letter=str(guess[:1])
  if guess_letter in ["a", "A"]:
    Row=0
  elif guess_letter in ["b", "B"]:
    Row=1
  elif guess_letter in ["c", "C"]:
    Row=2
  #Converting the number into a list coordinate
  Col=int(guess[1:])-1

  #Test to see if they guessed treasure location
  if grid[Row][Col]==1:
    print(" ")
    print("found treasure!")
    quit()
  else:
    print(" ")
    print("Treasure not here!")

#Loop for the main game
while True:
 _init_(turns, guess)
```

Comment: it looks like `guess` does not have an integral value.

Comment: Well… what exactly is the value of `guess[1:]` you're trying to parse as an `int`?

Comment: Could it be that at this point `guess` equals still just `x` because you set inside `validate_entry()` and did not assign it in the `_init_` function.

Answer (score 0):

After validating the user's input you didn't return the value to be used later on, so the guess value remains as "x" as when the code was initialized

Try changing the validate_entry function and the *init* function

```
def validate_entry():
  valid=False
  while valid==False:
    guess=input("Enter a location from A1 to C3: ")
    loc = guess.upper() #Use upper case
    row = guess[0:1]
    col = guess[1:2]
    if(row!="A" and row!="B" and row!="C") or (col!="1" and col!="2" and col!="3"):
      print("Your location is invalid.")
      print("")
      return False #not actually needed, but helps see what is happening
    else:
     valid=True
     return guess


def _init_(turns):
  turns=turns+1
 #If the player exceeds three turns they lose
  if turns>3:
    print("Too many turns! You lose!")
    quit()

  #Prints number of turns
  print(" ")
  print("Turn " + str(turns))
  guess = validate_entry()
  #Converting the letter into a coordinate in the list
  guess_letter=str(guess[:1])
  if guess_letter in ["a", "A"]:
    Row=0
  elif guess_letter in ["b", "B"]:
    Row=1
  elif guess_letter in ["c", "C"]:
    Row=2
  #Converting the number into a list coordinate
  Col=int(guess[1:])-1

  #Test to see if they guessed treasure location
  if grid[Row][Col]==1:
    print(" ")
    print("found treasure!")
    quit()
  else:
    print(" ")
    print("Treasure not here!")

_init_(turns)
```

The validate_entry function now returns the guess value, which is then passed on to the *init* function inside the function call

Side note: you can use `guess_letter.upper() == "A"` instead of guess_letter in ["a", "A"]. The `upper()` helps to convert the letter to uppercase. But you might want to check if `guess_letter.isalpha()` before that. I think this way might be easier because you just need to change one character after that. Another way is to get the index of the letter in string.ascii_uppercase after testing that it is an alpha

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter to `int()`. They passed in an empty string.

Comment: Oops, just tested his code, will make changes to answer

Comment: Amended the code, realised that it's because the value from validate_entry was not passed into _init_ function

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. This improved using the suggestions imptoved the situaton somewhat, but it is not liking the _init_(turns) line. i.e. receiving the following error now.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 88, in <module>
  File "python", line 84, in _init_
TypeError: _init_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'guess'

Any advice?

Comment: Oops, delete the guess from def _init_ so replace def _init_(turns,guess) with def _init_(turns)

Comment: I've changed it in the answer

Comment: Did that. it is now def _init_(turns):

It now errors thus:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 88, in <module>
TypeError: _init_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: And... interestingly changing it back to
def _init_(turns,guess):
and then calling _init_(turns,guess) in line 84 fixes that particular problem but now my validate coordinate function is having a problem. i.e. entering values outside the range results in this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 42, in <module>
  File "python", line 40, in settingTreasure
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Because if the value is incorrect, you are returning False (you added that it's to see what's going on), just change that line to valid = False for the while loop to run again after you're done testing that part

Comment: And using def _init_(turns) and calling _init_(turns) doesn't work?

Comment: No, using def_init_turns and calling _init_(turns didn't work form me). I've hashed out line 61 altogether with the return False and that seems to have done the trick.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if you could accept my answer that would be great